# preg_replace anything, including dots and slashes

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

For a small sized template engine, I'm trying to use a preg_replace to replace

`{INCLUDE:dir/file.inc.php}`

with the proper PHP equivalent.

I've tried using the following, but the / in the include path results in a "Division by zero" error:

`$template = preg_replace('~\{INCLUDE:(.*?)}~', '<?php echo $1; ?>', $template);`

(the echo in the preg_replace is for debugging purposes, will be an include eventually)

When I remove the / from the include path (so it's just file.inc.php), it still removes all dots.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly I think this should work just fine

```
$template = preg_replace('~{INCLUDE:(.*?)}~', '<?php include \'$1\'; ?>', $template);
```

Your problem was caused by unquoted $1.